# How can understanding logs help a tester?

Tags: testing, logging, automation, manual

I am an automation + manual tester. I would like to understand the reason how understanding the logs of an application(which i am working on) help me in improving my testing skills.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming  as defined in the [help].

Answer (score 0):

You see, I am really new into android, but the reason logs are important is because they can help you track down issues, such as `Java.NullPointerExceptions` and can help you trace back to where the issues were. I think there is also a way to create an error dialogue in the log, which can tell you that an error occurred. This is particularly essential in debugging, where you need to solve a problem in your app. I hope this helps, and best of luck. I think you can search up how to write stuff into a log at certain areas. I think the way on how to Log is to access Log class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0):

By viewing logs you will get some ideas about the error, if it is data level fix you can release and fix directly without dev team help.

In Java some times Runtime exception will occur, it will not convey messages to you in the interface about the exact problem. By viewing log you can get some ideas about the Runtime exception.